# Pulumi import is throwing "Not authorized to perform this operation"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, pulumi

I'm trying to import existing vpc via pulumi.

```js
const stackName = pulumi.getStack()
var vpcName = stackName + "-defaultvpc"

console.log("CIDR Block is" + config.cidrBlock)

const envVpc = new aws.ec2.Vpc(vpcName, {
    cidrBlock: config.cidrBlock,
}, {import: config.vpcId});

module.exports = {
    appVpc: envVpc
}
```

And then I'm executing `pulumi up --stack test` .

In my understanding this command just supposed to import the existing vpc into this test stack.

But during this execution, I'm getting the following error message.

*error: Preview failed: refreshing urn:pulumi:test::identity::aws:ec2/vpc:Vpc::test-defaultvpc: UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.*

I've confirmed that I've all read permissions for the VPC in aws account. But unable to find out what is the exact permission pulumi requires for this operation.

Answer (score 2):

This suggests you don't have authorization from AWS. From the command line where you're running pulumi, do you get the desired vpc in the results when running `aws ec2 describe-vpcs`?

If you do not, then you'll have to make sure that you have the DescribeVPC permission policy for that VPC.

Comment: I'm able to get the response for ''' aws ec2 describe-vpcs ''' from the instance where I'm running this pulumi up.  Not sure how to check where it exactly fails. With --debug also, i can't get the trace of this.